# Reporting Services 2008 Pie Chart from multiple fields

Tags: reporting-services, pie-chart

I want a pie chart where each of these values represent a slice of the value `Total_nr_of_shipments`:

```
Late_delivery_forwarder_fault,
Late_delivery_shipper_fault,
Late_delivery_consignee_fault,
Late_delivery_other
```

and the slice that represents the remaining part of the `total number of shipments` that makes up the shipments delivered on time.

How would you solve this?
Is it possible or is there a better way to show the performance figures?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the total of all slices equal to the total of shipments, then this chart will definitely work.

```
Late_delivery_forwarder_fault  20
Late_delivery_shipper_fault    20
Late_delivery_consignee_fault  20
Late_delivery_other            20
Delivered_on_time              20 
-----------------------------------
Total Shipments               100
```

If the totals do not equal the total number of shipments, then it means you have some kind of subset data.  In that case, a chart would not represent the data properly.  If this is the case, you would be better off with a Bar Chart.

Comment: Hi Jon, the thing is that I can't create a calculated field like Delivered_on_time and use it in the chart as this gives on error. You can not use aggregate functions there. And how do I make the Series show the names "Late_deliveries...." instead of the numbers?
Thank you for the help and hope I have clarified the problem.